# Javafx TableView goes out of focus after cell edit

Tags: javafx, focus, tableview

A starter in javafx, I need some help.
I followed the example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) and got the cell edit working perfectly.
I enabled the cell selection of the TableViewsetCellSelectionEnabled true in TableViewSelectionModel. But when I finish editing the cell, the TableView loses focus and the focus goes to the first node in the scene. I tried getting the currently selected cell and use focus() of getFocusModel() even in a Platform.runLater but no result.

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

A workaround could be to request the focus on the setEditOnCommit:

```
    firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, String> event) {
            table.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```